# SQL replacement for Recursive CTE

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, recursive-cte, wx2

I have a table Test which contains

```
TEST
----
tablename|columnvalue|rankofcolumn
A|C1|1
A|C2|2
A|C3|3
A|C4|4
B|CX1|1
B|CX2|2
C|CY1|1
C|CY2|2
C|CY3|3
```

I want to generate the path along with other columns as follows

```
RESULT
----
tablename|columnvalue|rankofcolumn|path
A|C1|1|C1
A|C2|2|C1->C2
A|C3|3|C1->C2->C3
A|C4|4|C1->C2->C3->C4
B|CX1|1|CX1
B|CX2|2|CX1->CX2
C|CY1|1|CY1
C|CY2|2|CY1->CY2
C|CY3|3|CY1->CY2->CY3
```

As per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357330/dynamic-sql-using-config-tables), I can use recursive CTE to achieve this

```
WITH r ( tablename, columnvalue, rankofcolumn, PATH ) AS
         (SELECT    tablename,
                    columnvalue,
                    rankofcolumn,
                    columnvalue
          FROM      test
          WHERE     rankofcolumn = 1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    xx.tablename,
                    xx.columnvalue,
                    xx.rankofcolumn,
                    r.PATH || '->' || xx.columnvalue
          FROM      r
                    JOIN test xx
                        ON     xx.tablename = r.tablename
                           AND xx.rankofcolumn = r.rankofcolumn + 1)
SELECT    *
FROM      r;
```

But I am using WX2 database which lacks this option at the moment. Is there a SQL alternative for this?

Comment: WX2 won't facilitate the CTE or you are asking another solution for this output

Comment: In the previous question you said intermediate tables were allowed; is that still OK?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yep. We can have intermediate tables or views.

Comment: @mohan111 yes, I am asking another solution for this output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the brute-force approach with a table that you gradually populate. Assuming your `test` table looks something like:

```
create table test (tablename varchar2(9), columnvalue varchar2(11), rankofcolumn number);
```

then the `result` table could be created with:

```
create table result (tablename varchar2(9), columnvalue varchar2(11), rankofcolumn number,
  path varchar2(50));
```

Then create the result entries for the lowest rank:

```
insert into result (tablename, columnvalue, rankofcolumn, path)
select t.tablename, t.columnvalue, t.rankofcolumn, t.columnvalue
from test t
where t.rankofcolumn = 1;

3 rows inserted.
```

And repeatedly add rows building on the highest existing rank, getting the following values (if there are any for that `tablename`) from the `test` table:

```
insert into result (tablename, columnvalue, rankofcolumn, path)
select t.tablename, t.columnvalue, t.rankofcolumn,
  concat(concat(r.path, '->'), t.columnvalue)
from test t
join result r
on r.tablename = t.tablename
and r.rankofcolumn = t.rankofcolumn - 1
where t.rankofcolumn = 2;

3 rows inserted.

insert into result (tablename, columnvalue, rankofcolumn, path)
select t.tablename, t.columnvalue, t.rankofcolumn,
  concat(concat(r.path, '->'), t.columnvalue)
from test t
join result r
on r.tablename = t.tablename
and r.rankofcolumn = t.rankofcolumn - 1
where t.rankofcolumn = 3;

2 rows inserted.

insert into result (tablename, columnvalue, rankofcolumn, path)
select t.tablename, t.columnvalue, t.rankofcolumn,
  concat(concat(r.path, '->'), t.columnvalue)
from test t
join result r
on r.tablename = t.tablename
and r.rankofcolumn = t.rankofcolumn - 1
where t.rankofcolumn = 4;

1 row inserted.
```

And keep going for the maximum possible number of columns (i.e. highest `rankofcolumn` for any table). You may be able to do that procedurally in WX2, iterating until zero rows are inserted; but you've made it sound pretty limited.

After all those iterations the table now contains:

```
select * from result
order by tablename, rankofcolumn;

TABLENAME COLUMNVALUE RANKOFCOLUMN PATH                                             
--------- ----------- ------------ --------------------------------------------------
A         C1                     1 C1                                                
A         C2                     2 C1->C2                                            
A         C3                     3 C1->C2->C3                                        
A         C4                     4 C1->C2->C3->C4                                    
B         CX1                    1 CX1                                               
B         CX2                    2 CX1->CX2                                          
C         CY1                    1 CY1                                               
C         CY2                    2 CY1->CY2                                          
C         CY3                    3 CY1->CY2->CY3
```

Tested in Oracle but trying to avoid anything Oracle-specific; might need tweaking for WX2 of course.

Comment: Thanks @Alex on this bit. But if we can do all these steps inside a JOIN?? I can have a config table to say the levels and do a CROSS JOIN to achieve this?

Comment: Not without recursion. You can't create/insert inside a select; that's partly why CTEs are useful. You could, I suppose, have a (non-recursive) CTE that does a bunch of unions, with progressively more self-joins in each one, but that's even messier.

Comment: Appreciate this genuine effort of yours. Thanks mate